# j2me form how to define gui properties

Tags: forms, java-me

i'm new to j2me. how to set form elements (text field ,text box) **width,font,alignment** and other Gui related properties.

i tried to find solution for setting *form background* but no success. can you guide me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, J2ME is a very limited framework.

As far as I can remember if you are just using an item from the basic javax.microedition.lcdui package there is very limited styling available. It allows you to give directives on how to lay the item out on the screen and what the item's appearance mode will be.

An [Item](http://download.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/Item.html) is not responsible for where it is placed and is down to the Screens layout management algorithm to place your item on the Screen. For example, the way Items are laid out on [Forms](http://download.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/Form.html) and [Lists](http://download.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/List.html) differ based upon how the layout management works.

You can create your own customs items by extending [CustomItem](http://download.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/CustomItem.html) and implementing and overriding various functions to get the desired visual effect. This however is a lot of work
and the end result is not always very pleasing. You could also do the same by extending the Form class and overriding the paint methods to get your disered visual effect.

The best way to have control over form elements is to use one of the Widget like frameworks that exist and are built upon these basic J2ME classes. For example [LWUIT](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javame/javamobile/download/lwuit/index.html) and [J2ME Polish](http://www.enough.de/products/j2me-polish/) allow you to style items in a very similar manner and layout Items using a CSS box inspired manner.

Although I have no used LWUIT so cannot vouch for it.

Comment: If you are satisified with my answer would you mind accepting it?